# Limited check in the CheckBox in Blazor

Tags: c#, checkbox, blazor

I made a blazor page which contains the  list of input of type checkbox. I am able to get the selected checkbox items using onchange event but I want to restirct the max checkbox selection up to 3 and if user try to check the fourth checkbox then the message box should appear  can't select more than three and the fourth checkbox should not be check. So how can I achive it?

@foreach (var option in ListItems) { <input type="checkbox" @onchange="()=>GetSelectedCheckbox(option)" /> @option.CheckboxName

}

@code {

```
[Parameter]
public List<ListItem> ListItems{ get; set; }

[Parameter]
public List<ListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<List<ListItem>> SelectedItemsChanged { get; set;}

private void GetSelectedCheckbox(ListItem items)
{
   //logic for max limit missing
    if (SelectedItems.Contains(items))
    {
        SelectedItems.Remove(items);
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedItems.Add(items);
    }
  SelectedItemsChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedItems);
}
```

}

Comment: You should really provide some code for the question to be answered.

Comment: You can check if SelectedItems.Count is less then 3 and prevent adding your checkbox to the list. The popup can be achived by injecting IJSRuntime into your component/page.

Comment: @MarvinKlein I did that, then it is not coming in my selected list but in html I am able to check in all checkbox.

Comment: @user17013672you should use @bind and use it with .NET 7 get/set/after modifiers. For example: `@bind="item.Checked" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="GetSelectedCheckbox"`

Comment: @MarvinKlein I am on .Net 6 and using  onchange and not bind. Can I achive in this way.

Comment: Then I would use an EditForm and <InputCheckbox to achive this. Will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MyInput
{
    public List<MyCheckbox> Options { get; set; } = new List<MyCheckbox>();
}

public class MyCheckbox
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}


<EditForm Model="Input">
@foreach (var option in Input.Options) 
{ 
    <InputCheckbox Value="@option.IsChecked" 
                   ValueChanged="(bool value) => CheckboxValueChanged(option, value)"
                   ValueExpression="() => option.IsChecked"> @option.CheckboxName

}
</EditForm>


@code {
    public MyInput Input { get; set; } = new MyInput();

    private void CheckboxValueChanged(MyCheckbox checkbox, bool value)
    {
        // Check value
        if(!value)
        {
            checkbox.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if allready n options are selected
            int numberChecked = Input.Options.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Count();

            if(numberChecked < 3)
            {
                checkbox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The magic here is using a extra class to hold the state of the checkbox.

Comment: This is correct but is thre any work around to achieve as input type and not as edit form

Comment: I'm not sure about it but it might be working when setting the checked attribute to the state of your object

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that builds a custom component to handle the checkboxes.

This uses binding for communications to/from the component.  The complex bit is getting the component to forget the selection when there's too many.  We do this by forcing a render with an empty list to reset the render tree.

The component:

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<div>

    @foreach (var item in ItemList)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="@this.Selected(item)" @onchange="() => this.SetItem(item)"> @item
        </div>
    }

    @if (_message is not null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@_message</div>
    }

</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext? _editContext { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public List<string> ItemList { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public int MaxItems { get; set; } = 2;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>?> ItemsChanged { get; set; }

    private string? _message;


    private async Task SetItem(string? value)
    {
        _message = null;

        if (value is null)
            return;

        if (this.Items.Any(item => item.Equals(value)))
        {
            this.Items.Remove(value);
            await this.ItemsChanged.InvokeAsync(Items);
            return;
        }

        if (this.Items.Count >= MaxItems)
        {
            // Force a reset of the list as we need to remove the x+1 item
            // To do this we set a empty list, render the component 
            // and then reset the list to thw actual values
            // This forces the diffing engine to see the changes and apply them to the DOM
            var items = this.ItemList;
            this.ItemList = new();
            this.StateHasChanged();
            await Task.Delay(1);
            this.ItemList = items;

            _message = "Too many Items selected";
            return;
        }

        this.Items.Add(value);

        await this.ItemsChanged.InvokeAsync(Items);
    }

    private bool Selected(string value)
    {
        return this.Items.Any(item => item.Equals(value));
    }
}
```

And a demo `Index`

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <MySelector @bind-Items=this.Selected ItemList=this.Countries />
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    @foreach(var item in Selected)
    {
        <pre>
            @item
        </pre>
        
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<string> Selected = new();

    private List<string> Countries = new() {"France", "Portugal", "UK", "Spain" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem with js function call approach and dotnet method call in js. may this is not the best way to do it but I achived What I needed.

```
@foreach (var option in ListItems)
{
<input type="checkbox" class="check" @onchange="()=> GetSelectedCheckbox(option)" />@option.CheckboxName
}




[Parameter]
public List<ListItem> ListItems{ get; set; }

[Parameter]
public List<ListItem> SelectedItems { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<List<ListItem>> SelectedItemsChanged { get; set;}

private void GetSelectedCheckbox(ListItem items)
{
   
    if (SelectedItems.Contains(items))
    {
        SelectedItems.Remove(items);
    }
    else
    {
       await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("attachHandler",
       DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), nameof(JStoCSCall));
       SelectedItems.Add(items);
    }
  SelectedItemsChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedItems);
}


// Return call back from JavaScript to C#
    [JSInvokable]
    public void JStoCSCall()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Upto max 3 items can be selected");
       StateHasChanged();
    }





//Javascript limit selected checkboxes

    window.attachHandler = (dotnet, callback) => {
        var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
        var max = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
            checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;
        function selectiveCheck() {
            var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".check:checked");
            if (checkedChecks.length >= max + 1) {
                dotnet.invokeMethodAsync(callback);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I see that you've accepted your own answer, which kind of defeats the purpose of using Blazor.  The only thing you should need Javascript for is media functionality (streaming video etc.)

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 you are right. That's why I wrote that this is not the good approach. I removed the answer as accepted.

Comment: Good.  The answers already given are good.  I'll try to provide a minimal example if I can.  Some advice, though.  If Shaun has already written an answer, 99% chance that will be the best one. :D